# PUT method is not supported for route vehiculos/7676729/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to understand PHP Laravel but can't figure out how to make this put operation.
Basically I have my db created with artisan and the table for vehiculos is simple.

```
Schema::create('vehiculos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->foreign('idFk')->references('id')->on('clientes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('marca');
            $table->string('modelo');
            $table->year('anio');
            $table->string('matricula')->primary();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

I just want to be able to change the vehicle data, of course cannot change id neither the matricula (license plate), everything goes well except using the PUT operation. Gives me this error: The PUT method is not supported for route vehiculos/7676729/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

What it confuses me is that I'm doing the exact thing at another class being Client where I update it and works like a charm, here doesn't.

This is my VehiculoController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, Vehiculo $vehiculo) {
        // Define las reglas de validación
        $request->validate([
            'matricula' => 'required|unique:vehiculos' . $vehiculo->matricula,
            'id' => 'required' . $vehiculo->id,
            'marca' => 'required',
            'modelo' => 'required',
            'anio' => 'required',
        ]);
        $vehiculo->update($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('vehiculos.listar')->with('success', 'Vehiculo
        actualizado con éxito.');
    }
```

My web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/clientes', [ClienteController::class, 'index'])->name('clientes.index');

Route::resource('clientes', ClienteController::class)
    ->names([
        'index' => 'clientes.listar',
        'create' => 'clientes.crear',
        'store' => 'clientes.guardar',
        'show' => 'clientes.ver',
        'edit' => 'clientes.editar',
        'update' => 'clientes.actualizar',
        'destroy' => 'clientes.eliminar',
    ]);

Route::resource('vehiculos', VehiculoController::class)
    ->names([
        'index' => 'vehiculos.listar',
        'create' => 'vehiculos.crear',
        'store' => 'vehiculos.guardar',
        'show' => 'vehiculos.ver',
        'edit' => 'vehiculos.editar',
        'update' => 'vehiculos.actualizar',
        'destroy' => 'vehiculos.eliminar',
    ]);
```

My edit.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editar vehiculos</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Modificar vehiculo</h1>
    @if (session('success'))
        <div>{{session('success')}}</div>
    @endif
    <form action="{{route('vehiculos.editar', $vehiculo->matricula)}}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method("PUT")
        <label for="matricula" >matricula:</label>
        <input type="text" name="matricula" value="{{$vehiculo->matricula}}" readonly>
        <label for="id">id:</label>
        <input type="text" name="id" value="{{$vehiculo->id}}" readonly>
        <label for="marca">marca:</label>
        <input type="text" name="marca" value="{{$vehiculo->marca}}">
        <label for="modelo">modelo:</label>
        <input type="text" name="modelo" value="{{$vehiculo->modelo}}">
        <label for="anio">anio:</label>
        <input type="text" name="anio" value="{{$vehiculo->anio}}">
        <button type="submit">ENVIAR</button>

        @if ($errors->all())
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <ul>
            <li>{{$error}}</li>
            </ul>
            @endforeach
            
        @endif
    </form>
</body>
```

And my index.blade.php

```
<h1>Lista de vehiculos</h1>
    @if(session('success'))
    <div style="color: green;">
        {{ session('success') }}
    </div>
    @endif
    <a href="{{ route('vehiculos.crear') }}">Crear Nuevo vehiculo</a>
    <ul>
        @foreach ($vehiculos as $vehiculo)
        <li>{{ $vehiculo->marca }} - {{ $vehiculo->modelo }}
            <a href="{{ route('vehiculos.ver', $vehiculo -> id) }}">Ver</a>
            <a href="{{ route('vehiculos.editar', $vehiculo -> id) }}">Editar</a>
            <form action="{{ route('vehiculos.eliminar', $vehiculo -> id) }}" method="POST">
                @csrf
                @method('DELETE')
                <button type="submit">Eliminar</button>
            </form>
        </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Also my routes available for vehiculos when I launch artisan route:list

```
GET|HEAD        vehiculos ................................................................ vehiculos.listar › VehiculoController@index
  POST            vehiculos ............................................................... vehiculos.guardar › VehiculoController@store
  GET|HEAD        vehiculos/create ......................................................... vehiculos.crear › VehiculoController@create
  GET|HEAD        vehiculos/{vehiculo} ......................................................... vehiculos.ver › VehiculoController@show
  PUT|PATCH       vehiculos/{vehiculo} ................................................ vehiculos.actualizar › VehiculoController@update
  DELETE          vehiculos/{vehiculo} ................................................. vehiculos.eliminar › VehiculoController@destroy
  GET|HEAD        vehiculos/{vehiculo}/edit ................................................. vehiculos.editar › VehiculoController@edit
```

Make a PUT request and change the data, for example the year or model of the vehicle and see it change in the database, but whenever I try or change PUT to PATCH gives me the same error.

Edit: Also changing the method to PUT in this line gets the same result, but without error, it just does nothing

matricula)}}" method="POST">

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<form action="{{route('vehiculos.editar', $vehiculo->matricula)}}"`

to

`<form action="{{route('vehiculos.actualizar', $vehiculo->matricula)}}"`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `vehiculos.actualizar` route and not `vehiculos.editar` since `vehiculos.editar` opens the edit view page and `vehiculos.actualizar` opens the put route.